# nouveau: suspend failed with -110

Tags: boot

It shows me this when I open my computer and stuck there:

[image]

Comment: @heynnema when i pressed ctrl alt f3 i type my login informations but nothing happened after

Comment: OK, last attempt. Boot to Recovery Mode, Root Access, again. Type `sudo blkid | grep -i swap` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Edit that output into your question, not the comments. Ping me with a @heynnema comment when you have that info.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110713/discussion-on-question-by---nouveau-suspend-failed-with-110).